# How to pull resourcegroups user/groups permissions from azure powershell or CLI

Tags: powershell, azure, resources

I want to pull list of users/groups permissions for resource group wise for all the resource groups in the subscription.
can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this documentation from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-powershell